# Putting stuff in Map<?,?> or converting Map<String,String> to Map<?,?>

Tags: java, generics, easymock, type-erasure

I'm unhappily dealing with an interface someone defined with the following

```
public Map<?, ?> getMap(String key);
```

I'm trying to write unit tests that consume this interface.

```
Map<String,String> pageMaps = new HashMap<String,String();
pageMaps.put(EmptyResultsHandler.PAGEIDENT,"boogie");
pageMaps.put(EmptyResultsHandler.BROWSEPARENTNODEID, "Chompie");
Map<?,?> stupid = (Map<?, ?>)pageMaps;
EasyMock.expect(config.getMap("sillyMap")).andReturn(stupid);
```

and the compiler is borking.

```
The method andReturn(Map<capture#5-of ?,capture#6-of ?>) in the type IExpectationSetters<Map<capture#5-of ?,capture#6-of ?>> is not applicable for the arguments (Map<capture#7-of ?,capture#8-of ?>)
```

If I try to use `pageMaps` directly, it tells me:

```
The method andReturn(Map<capture#5-of ?,capture#6-of ?>) in the type IExpectationSetters<Map<capture#5-of ?,capture#6-of ?>> is not applicable for the arguments (Map<String,String>)
```

If I make `pageMaps` a `Map<?,?>`, I can't put Strings inside of it.

```
The method put(capture#3-of ?, capture#4-of ?) in the type Map<capture#3-of ?,capture#4-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)
```

I've seen some client code that does ugly unchecked conversions, like

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Map<String, String> emptySearchResultsPageMaps = (Map<String, String>) conf.getMap("emptySearchResultsPage");
```

How do I get data into a `Map<?,?>`, or convert my `Map<String,String>` to `Map<?,?>` ?

Comment: There is kind of confusion here: You try to convince the compiler that stupid is a Map with 2 type arguments *you don't care about*, but nevertheless, you use the Map at the type Map<String, String>. But what you should do is to test that the interface works for any combination of types you need.

Comment: What happens if you make it return `pageMaps`? `EasyMock.expect(config.getMap("sillyMap")).andReturn(pageMaps);`

Comment: I only care about it as a Map<String,String> for this test, but that is irrelevant. I don't see how I can "test that the interface works for any combination of types that I need" if I cannot get data into it. If I make the map completely generic, put() refuses to work.

Comment: @JBNizet That was what I meant by "when I true to use pageMaps directly"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There is no way you can write `Map<String, String> map = getMap("abc");` without a cast
2. The problem has more to do with easymock and the types returned/expected by the `expect` and `andReturn` methods, which I'm not familiar with. You could write

   ```
   Map<String, String> expected = new HashMap<String, String> ();
   Map<?, ?> actual = getMap("someKey");
   boolean ok = actual.equals(pageMaps);
   //or in a junit like syntax
   assertEquals(expected, actual);
   ```

Not sure if that can be mixed with your mocking stuff. This would maybe work:

```
EasyMock.expect((Map<String, String>) config.getMap("sillyMap")).andReturn(pageMaps);
```

Also note that you can't add anything to a generic collection with a wildcard. So this:

```
Map<?, ?> map = ...
map.put(a, b);
```

won't compile, unless `a` and `b` are null.

Comment: Nicely done, I hadn't thought of trying to cast inside of the expect call.